# When are Zookeeper TCP connections cleaned up server side?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

In a testing setup (single client server - localhost running Gatling, creating and closing connections during test) my single node Zookeeper keeps all TCP connections open until the test run completes.

During the test run in the first 2 minutes, I repeatedly create up to 10 client connections in parallel, that are alive for about 30 seconds and then close their connection again. So at any one moment there are up to 10 connections active in the first 2 minutes.
Then the test continues for another 8 minutes, during which there is just 1 client connection active.

Client side: using Curator 2.9.1 and Zookeeper 3.4.6

Zookeeper node: 3.4.8-1--1

AFAIK the clients properly close their connection (proof: I see it's ephemeral nodes are deleted when doing an ls /path/to/ephemerals, zookeeper logs indicate closed connections as well)

However, when sending the **cons** command to the zookeeper node, the number of TCP connections keeps rising in the first 2 minutes, up to a total of 126. It then stays at that number until the testrun is complete, at which moment all connections are gone at once.

I expected the number of connections to be way lower, like 10 to 20, and stable during the 'active' phase of the test. Instead it keeps rising as long as I open/close new connections.

During the initial 2 minutes, the zookeeper logs show opening and closing connections:

```
2016-03-25 15:54:04,305 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,321 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:ZooKeeperServer@900] - Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,324 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@645] - Established session 0x153ae440b2e000f with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,324 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:ZooKeeperServer@924] - got auth packet /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,325 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:ZooKeeperServer@958] - auth success /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,326 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:ZooKeeperServer@924] - got auth packet /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,328 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:ZooKeeperServer@958] - auth success /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:60758
2016-03-25 15:54:04,803 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:NIOServerCnxnFactory@192] - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:37236
2016-03-25 15:54:04,804 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:ZooKeeperServer@900] - Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:37236
2016-03-25 15:54:04,805 - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@645] - Established session 0x153ae440b2e0010 with negotiated timeout 10000 for client /127.0.0.1:37236
2016-03-25 15:54:04,828 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:12182)::PrepRequestProcessor@489] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x153ae440b2e0010
2016-03-25 15:54:04,830 - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:12182:NIOServerCnxn@1008] - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:37236 which had sessionid 0x153ae440b2e0010
```

Then, only at the end of the run, for each connection I see

```
2016-03-25 15:57:44,002 - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@355] - Expiring session 0x153ae440b2e006c, timeout of 10000ms exceeded
2016-03-25 15:57:44,003 - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@355] - Expiring session 0x153ae440b2e00b8, timeout of 10000ms exceeded
2016-03-25 15:57:44,003 - INFO  [SessionTracker:ZooKeeperServer@355] - Expiring session 0x153ae440b2e0094, timeout of 10000ms exceeded
...
2016-03-25 15:57:44,014 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:12182)::PrepRequestProcessor@489] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x153ae440b2e006c
2016-03-25 15:57:44,014 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:12182)::PrepRequestProcessor@489] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x153ae440b2e00b8
2016-03-25 15:57:44,015 - INFO  [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:12182)::PrepRequestProcessor@489] - Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x153ae440b2e0094
...
```

(note that the above log was taken from a manually interrupted run, but the behaviour is the same if I had let the run complete to 16:02)

I am running with the following config (excerpt):

```
tickTime=2000
maxSessionTimeout=10000
minSessionTimeout=4000
maxClientCnxns=0
```

Is the rising number of connections related to the test setup, or it inherent in the way Zookeeper operates?

Comment: Are you sure that the actual tcp-connections are open during the entire test? What does something like `netstat -anp --tcp` show? It might just be zookeeper that monitors the connections.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure the connections are actually there. In fact, closer inspection of our client side code revealed that the connection got shut down in an incorrect way (the actual connection.close was omitted <facepalm />). So it was not an issue with Zookeeper nor Gatling.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an error in our client code. The connections did not properly get closed, only half of the cleanup was done (ephemeral nodes got deleted allright, but the client connection was in fact not really closed).

Apologies for taking up your time.